# bootstrap hamburger not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to figure out where i went wrong but i see nothing wrong.. let people with sharp eyes tell me where i went wrong. the code is shown below..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


    <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#icons">
                <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zack</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="icons">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>





<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

much appreciated stackoverflow developers. :)

Comment: Please could you complete the question with the expected results or why you think it's not working ?

Comment: thats the whole code. when i click the hamburger, it should have expanded with nav menus showing up but it is not working. @PRMoureu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only included jQuery and it's working fine. You are most likely missing the *jquery-3.2.1.js* file or the src path to it is incorrect.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#icons">
      <span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Zack</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="icons">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your head

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

basically you forget to trigger viewport
this should work

Comment: i added that and it still not working.. @Rushabh sheth

Comment: `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">` try this